# Disable text selection on nested span (React / Electron)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, electron

I have some nested spans.

```
<span>
 <span>Title</span>
 <span>Author</span>
 <span>Year</span>
</span>
```

When the user tries to select them, everything will be selected (with the blue background behind the selected text). However, I want only one span to be selectable, so that the user cannot go wrong and can only select, for example, the author field.

I have tried making the other fields not selectable by doing this:

```
.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */

  /* No support for these yet, use at own risk */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

and then in my html:

```
<span>
 <span class="unselectable">Title</span>
 <span>Author</span>
 <span class="unselectable">Year</span>
</span>
```

But it does not work, I can still select everything. I am using React & electron, if this should make a difference.

Comment: here is working same code https://jsfiddle.net/z78o251e/

Comment: thank you. as I said in my post though, this does not work for me in electron.